# Adjustable nested symbols in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, resize, symbols

Is it possible to create nested symbols that are adjustable when we choose "none" status?

I'm looking for a way to make the symbol disappear and other symbols would move to adjust the space between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible. The closest you will get is to use a plugin like [Compo](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/compo-sketch) to help resizing elements when the content changes.

Comment: In addition to Compo, [Anima's Auto-Layout](https://animaapp.github.io/docs/v1/auto-layout/12-stacks-flexbox.html) is one we use here at Wiretap all the time 